# Who was the last Samukh (סמוך)?

Tags: history, historical-figures

Who was the last 'Samukh' (סמוך)?

Rambam stated in the introduction of his book,  that the last Sanhedrin (סנהדרין) was a little before the Talmud was edited. But it says nothing about the last person who was Samukh.

Also, it is interesting why the last person didn't continue the 'Semikha' in order to keep it in Israel.

Comment: Rav Aaron Lopiansky in his series of biographical sketches says about R' Yosef Cairo (author of the Beis Yosef and Shulchan Aruch and more) that he was the last one. But it was given to him by a group of 100 rabbanim, not through a chain of Rav to talmid. Here is a link to the shiur online: https://shiurim.eshelpublications.com/beis-yosef/